# Oracle SQL subquery expecting missing right paranthesis

Tags: oracle

I dislike Oracle by the way, but i'm trying to get a simple query to work

```
select * from d1.Table where Updated = (select updated from d1.dates where rownum=1 order by updated)
```

I run the subquery and it runs perfectfly fine:

```
select updated from d1.dates where rownum=1 order by updated
```

However when I run the entire statement I get an error, an dit highlights ORDER in the query as if that is the problem.

```
[1]: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle 12c you can use `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY`:

```sql
select *
from   d1.Table
where  Updated = (
  select updated
  from   d1.dates
  order by updated
  FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
)
```

or join the tables and use `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES`:

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM   d1.table t
       INNER JOIN d1.dates d
       ON ( t.updated = d.updated )
ORDER BY d.updated
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

or, in earlier version, you can use the `RANK` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY d.updated ) AS rnk
  FROM   d1.table t
         INNER JOIN d1.dates d
         ON ( t.updated = d.updated )
)
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```